# How do I correctly use the jenkins 'publish over ssh' plugin in a jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

The documentation on https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ssh/#code-sshpublisher-code-send-build-artifacts-over-ssh is not too clear...

```
sshPublisher publishers transfer sourceFiles: '/appdata/jenkins/jobs/project/otcm-${pom.version}.tar.gz'
```

The above gives me 'no such property' errors. What's the proper syntax for this?

My jenkinsfile:

```
node {
stage 'Clean Up'
deleteDir()

stage 'Env Setup'
env.JAVA_HOME = "${tool 'JDK 8'}"
def mvnHome = tool '3.0.3'

stage 'Compile/Package'
checkout scm

stage 'Compile/Package - Get app version'

def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'

echo "${pom.version}"

stage 'Compile/Package - Compile and upload to S3'
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean install -DskipTests"

/* should i bother with pushing to s3 since snapshot? */
stage 'Push to S3'

stage 'Install'
sh "ssh devci@server 'rm -rf /appdata/devci/app'"
sh "ssh devci@server 'mkdir /appdata/devci/app'"

/* ssh push the tar to remote dir */
/* use the jenkins sshPublisher??? */

/* Remote - explode tar */
/* Remote - download project properties */
/* Remove - start app without new relic using custom port 8007 */
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so there's this pipeline snippet generator!

https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/31/pipeline-snippetizer/

very useful for beginners!